# writing math table using multidimension array

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write the math table from 1 to table using a `for` loop and storing into a multidimensional array but couldn't do so. Whenever I executed the script I get the following error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Examples\PHP_Object.php
>   Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Examples\PHP_Object.php

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$tbl=array();
echo "<table >";
$x=0;
$y=0;
for ($tb = 1 ; $tb <= 10; $tb++) {
    echo"<tr>";
    $tbl[$x] = array();
    for($no = 1;$no <=10; $no++ ) {
        $z = $tb * $no ;
        $tbl[$x][$y];
        echo "<th> $tbl[$x][$y] = $z </th>";
        $y = $y+1;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $x = $x+1;
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $tbl=array();
    echo "<table >";
    $x=0;
    $y=0;
    for ($tb = 1 ; $tb <= 10; $tb++) {
    echo"<tr>";
    $tbl[$x] = array();
        for($no = 1;$no <=10; $no++ ) {
            $z = $tb * $no ;
            $tbl[$x][$y] = $z;
            echo "<th> ".$tbl[$x][$y]. "</th>";
        $y = $y+1;
        }
     echo "</tr>";
     $x = $x+1;
     }
     echo "</table>";
     ?>
```

The below lines in your code were wrong:

```
$tbl[$x][$y];
echo "<th> $tbl[$x][$y] = $z </th>";
```

When you put something like `$tbl[$x][$y] = $z` inside double quote and `echo` that, PHP won't assign anything inside the variable rather it will try to echo out the value of the variables specified and the `=` sign will be considered as string that will be printed as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't do anything:

```
    $tbl[$x][$y];
```

You need an assignment to store into the array:

```
    $tbl[$x][$y] = $z;
```

This line is causing the warning message:

```
    echo "<th> $tbl[$x][$y] = $z </th>";
```

In order to interpolate a multidimensional array variable into a string, and also evaluate the indexes of an array, you have to enclose it in curly braces:

```
    echo "<th> {$tbl[$x][$y]} = $z </th>";
```

Since you didn't do this, it tried to print the entire `$tbl` array, but you can't print an array with `echo`.

But I don't see why you need to put both `$tbl[$x][$y]` and also `= $z` in the table, since they're the same thing, so you should just write:

```
    echo "<th> $z </th>";
```